# How to create generic AggregateService in Autofac

Tags: generics, autofac

You can do something like this:

Registration:

```
builder.RegisterAggregateService(typeof(IGenericAggregateService<>));
```

Constructor definition:

```
public Repository(IGenericAggregateService<TEntity> aggregateService)
```

but autofac can't resolve aggregateService parameter.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @KevinR. I'm trying to resolve generic type using AggregateService

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible. There is a workaround though. It involves a little bit of extra effort.

1. Create the generic aggregate service interface the same way you would create a normal aggregate service.
2. Create a generic aggregate service implementation with a constructor requesting all underlying services and set the properties with their provided values.
3. Register the generic aggregate service using the [open generics registration concept](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components).

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible as of **v6.1.0**. Just use the overload:

```
builder.RegisterAggregateService(typeof(IGenericAggregateService<>));
```

And it will be registered as generic!